# Counting addition in Fibonacci Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have both algorithms working properly. The two algorithms are Fibonacci algorithms, that will find the Fibonacci Number, at n, where user specifies n. I have three methods: two of which return the Fibonacci number at n, and the final method executes both methods while displaying all Fibonacci numbers in a tabular form, with a column corresponding to how many times ADDITION was executed in the code.

I've declared global counters recAdd, and itAdd that represent lines added in each algorithm respectively. These values are reset my test harness after each execution, but I do not show that here.

```
public static long recFib(int n){ //Recursive Fibonacci Algorithm
    if( n <= 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(n == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(n == 2){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        recAdd++;                               //Counts number of lines added.
        return recFib(n-1) + recFib(n-2);   //Recurisvely adds fibonnachi numbers. Starts with user's input n. Method is called repeatedly until n is less than 2.
    }
}

public static long itFib(int n){ //Iterative Fibonacci Algorithm
    long x, y, z;

    if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        x = 1;
        y = 1;

        for(int i = 3; i <=n; i++){
            z = x+y;        //z is equal to the addition of x and y, which serve as f(n-1) + f(n-2).
            x = y;      //x is shifted to the next fibonacci number, previously known as y.
            y = z;      //y is set equal to z, which was the new value created by the old y and the old x.
            itAdd++;        //counts how many times addition has occured.
        }
    }
    return y;
}   

public static void doTheyMatch(int n){

    System.out.printf("%s %15s %15s %15s %15s", "i", "Recursive", "recAddCount", "Iterative", "itAddCount\n\n"); //Tab header

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    System.out.printf("%d %12d %12d %12d %12d\n", i, recFib(i), recAdd, itFib(i), itAdd);       
    }

    System.out.printf("%s %15s %15s %15s %15s", "\ni", "Recursive", "recAddCount", "Iterative", "itAddCount\n"); //Repeat for quick referencing
}
```

Output is here (I have issues posting output in these text boxes =/): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrAcN.png

I am confident that the reason my addition counters are off so much during the 'doTheyMatch()' method is because of the loop that executes this method. (The method loops n times, and while it's looping, the Iterative and Recursion methods iterate inside their own method). I can't figure out another way to count the number of lines added. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: i didn't get what your problem is?

Comment: I'm counting how many times addition is performed in both algorithms separately. They lines are indeed counted correctly when executed separately (in the output image).

When I use the doTheyMatch() algorithm, both the iterative and recursive algorithms are executed, but the lines added aren't being calculated correctly. My question is: How can I use the method doTheyMatch() while at the same time getting the correct number of lines added correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't reset your addition counter on the doTheyMatch function

Should have done something like:

```
System.out.printf("%d %12d %12d %12d %12d\n", i, recFib(i), recAdd, itFib(i), itAdd);

// reset counters
recAdd = 0;
itAdd = 0;
```

Comment: The recAdd and itAdd lines do get reset. At the end of the while loop in my menu harness, I reset them, since after any choice on the menu, the switch case ends. If you look closely at the image I linked, the counter variables start off at 0 in final example, directly after I executed the recursive algorithm.

Comment: But the counters are static variables, you have to reset them per iteration of loop. Maybe review your lecture notes on "static variables"

Comment: Problem fixed. You were right, I wasn't thinking that I needed to reset the counter variables in the for loop of the doTheyMatch() method, whereas I reset the variables AFTER the method itself ended.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are trying to do here is that when you call the function recursively, the larger then number is, the more number of times the function is called. The possibility of your number being 0 or 1 is just 1 each so the function is called that many times. What you need to do is to put the `recAdd++;` statement inside these if blocks:

```
if( n <= 0){
    return 0;
}
if(n == 1){
    return 1;
}
else if(n == 2){
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because with recursion, the method calls branch, and you call the method multiple times during the recursive process. This means that it adds up at a faster rate then with iteration. Try mapping out a few method calls for smaller numbers on paper and track your itAdd and recAdd variables and you will see what I mean. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful to you but if you are trying to find the fibonacci of a certain number `n` you can use the formula `F(n) = (k^n-p^n)/sqrt(5)` where `n` is the number of iterations or the specific number in the sequence and `k = (1+sqrt(5))/2` and `p = (1-sqrt(5))/2`